# I am not sure whether the application is running on just the master or the whole cluster for Spark on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.1.1 . I followed the instructions given on https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/ec2-scripts.html and have a cluster of 1 master node and 1 worker on EC2 running.

I have made a jar of the application and rsynced it to the slaves. When I run the application using spark-submit with the deploy-mode of client, the application works. However, when I do so using deploy-mode cluster it gives me an error saying it cannot find the jar on the worker. The permission of the jar is 755 on both the master and worker.

I am not sure whether when I run the application using deploy-mode=client whether the application is using the workers. I don't think it is since the worker url does not show any completed jobs. But it does show failed jobs during deploy-mode=cluster.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not Spark 1.2.1?

Comment: I could run it. Do you that should help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if executors are assigned to the application on the `/executors` page on port 4040 (e.g. `http://localhost:4040/executors/`). If you only see `<driver>` then you are not using the worker. If you see one line for `<driver>` and one other line (with ID 0, unless it has restarted), then the worker is also providing an executor to your application. Here you can also see how many tasks it has completed for your application, and other stats.